# When are the stateful table entries for the stateful firewall created?

Tags: firewalls, tcp

We know the TCP 3-way handshake:

```
C->SYN->S
C<-SYN-ACK<-S
C->ACK->S
```

[image]

we also know stateful firewall.
When a stateful filter entry(`source ip`, `source port`, `dest ip`, `dest port`) create? after the 3-way handshake finish or just the first 2 step of it finish?

Comment: This is not a security question but a pure networking question.

Comment: and the answer is found on the wiki page for the topic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateful_firewall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `SYN` is a state of the connection, although it's not established yet between the two parties. If the firewall doesn't keep track of that, how would it be able to say that the `SYN-ACK` and `ACK` are part of the same connection? More importantly, how would it be able to treat unsuspected, potentially fabricated `SYN-ACK` or `ACK`? It certainly shouldn't allow those packets through.